# Using Zxing online qr code decoder using php

Tags: php, web-services, zxing

I am creating a website that requires me to decode qr codes. I did my research and found out that php does not natively support decoding of qr codes. So, I decided to use the webservices that provide decoding of qr codes. I came across a good webservice, Zxing, which decodes the image submitted to it. The problem that I found was that I could not find enough documentation online with regards to the usage of the Zxing webservices, like how should the parameters be passed to the url of the webservice. The url that I am to access is, http://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx,
but then how should I consume this webservice using SOAP / XML-RPC in php.
I studied the result that is returned when I click on the "Submit" button, and its a simple text document.
Please, do give me guidance as to how should I consume the Zxing webservice, are there any online documentations?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It's not really documented as an API since it's not an API. You are not meant to integrate for use in your own service. It's a site I run as a free courtesy to end users on the web. It's OK to send a few requests at it, but for any significant volume, please run your own.

But the HTML is pretty much all the documentation you need: you can see what URL it posts to, and what parameters it sends. It's really just a POST of image content under parameter 'f', or a GET to the same URL with parameter 'u' specifying a URL to load.

The complete source code is at http://code.google.com/p/zxing, under `zxingorg/`. You probably want to run your own copy, so you can control it and modify it.

Comment: @Sean Owen 
Could you please give some instruction to run the copy of zxing.org in my own server. I downloaded the .jar file from here https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/zxing/zxingorg/3.3.3/zxingorg-3.3.3-sources.jar

when running the file am getting an error. Your help is much appreciated in hosting the service 

java -jar zxingorg-3.3.3-sources.jar
no main manifest attribute, in zxingorg-3.3.3-sources.jar

Comment: You need the .war file, and you need to deploy it to a web app container like Tomcat

Comment: @Sean Owen I put .war on TomCat but it doesn't work like https://zxing.org/. show me 404 not found.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I want something like that: https://zxing.org/w/chart?cht=qr&chs=150x150&chld=H%7C6&choe=UTF-8&chl=%22%20+%20QrCode%20+%20%22